# AS5600 sensor raspberry pi4 / ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I am trying to read the AS5600 sensor with my raspberry pi 4. I tried this script (https://github.com/sgall17a/AS5600) but unfortunately I get an error every time. Can someone help me to read the AS5600 on the Raspberry pi4 with python?

**Error:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/software $ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from as5600 import *
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/software/as5600.py", line 1, in <module>
    from machine import I2C,Pin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine'
```

**I tried the following but still ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine':**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install machine
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting machine
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/ce/0c62600971471aabe55865c7100a886f3c2cad767e3a0af2dff717d08e68/machine-0.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pycrypto in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from machine) (2.6.1)
Installing collected packages: machine
Successfully installed machine-0.0.1
```

**After some googling I found out that I probably need "micropython-machine" so I tried it and got the next error:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install micropython-machine
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting micropython-machine
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/31/a3282942b3e96881393db406130735913c647f0fc9e07a0d60d7b546b06b/micropython-machine-0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-28u1A1/micropython-machine/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-28u1A1/micropython-machine/
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run [micropython](https://micropython.org/) code with regular Python. From the README in the linked repository:

> This is a Micropython library for reading an AS5600 using I2C. It was developed on a Seeedstudio board and Raspberry Pi Pico. It should work with other MCU's running Micropython but I2C setup may differ on on other boards. It may work on circuit python but I have not tested this.

You cannot run Micropython code with regular Python. This project is meant to run on a microcontroller (like the Pico).

You could port this code to Python; that would require replacing the use of the `machine` module with appropriate alternatives for interacting with the GPIO features of your raspberry pi. How to do that is probably outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the only script I found... How can I read out the AS5600?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address that question.